# Was the language real?

Tags: dialogue, isle-of-dogs

In the movie *Isle of Dogs* most of the human characters speak Japanese. Was it real Japanese language, or was it only some mumbling pretending to be Japanese or some funny lines that only a Japanese-speaking person would understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Japanese is 'real' for a slightly distorted version of 'reality'.

It is sometimes muffled, sometimes a little stilted and some of the signage is a little awkward.

I have a Japanese friend who saw it at the time and pointed some of this out to me, but I found a written reference to it on [Vulture: What It’s Like to Watch Isle of Dogs As a Japanese Speaker](https://www.vulture.com/2018/03/what-its-like-to-watch-isle-of-dogs-as-a-japanese-speaker.html)

Some extracts from the above ref...

> For what it’s worth, the spoken Japanese made complete sense, there was no accent or awkwardness
>
> The main [Japanese-speaking] characters, or anyone with relatively more dialogue, like Atari or Major-Domo, sounded a bit weird. They didn’t try to speak Japanese precisely, but they had a Japanese ‘cultural effect.’ So it was kind of caricatured.
>
> The written language, as it appears in the art direction and onscreen text, stood out more than the un-subtitled dialogue. “A lot of it was an awkward, kind of choppy phrasing. It kind of made me think that someone had thrown these English phrases into Google Translate. The [characters] weren’t the exact characters you would use in that context."